# Changing position of an object by a specific vertex in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, position, vertex

I want to change the position of an object by a specific vertex of that object in three.js. I have this .OBJ [glasses model](https://free3d.com/3d-model/frame-glasses-314946.html) which has [8,856 vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nurdY.png). Here is my code:

**Note:** [OBJLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js) is necessary.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vertices Positioning</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas
      id="modelCanvas"
      width="600px"
      height="400px"
    ></canvas>
  </body>

  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 600 / 400, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true,
  canvas: modelCanvas,
});
renderer.setSize(600, 400);
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
let obj3D = new THREE.Object3D();

loader.load(
  "./model.obj",
  function (obj) {
    obj3D = obj;
    console.log(obj3D);
    scene.add(obj3D);
  }
);

camera.position.z = 5;

const render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

What I mean is that let's say, the object is in its [default location of 0, 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqsbo.jpg) (Red dot: default position, Cyan dot: Vertex position). Now if I want to get the position of a specific vertex (top left corner) and [change the vertex's position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAzoy.jpg), the object's position also changes (Cyan Dot: Object position, Blue Dot: New Vertex position). That's what I want to achieve in Three.js.

**Bonus:**

I did some research and found out that the vertices are located in Object3D > Children > (Index of the Mesh) > geometry > attributes, [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Dj5.jpg). This contains normal, position and uv. And each one of them contains an array of vertices. But this array only contains one position number, so I don't know if it is X-axis, Y-Axis or Z-Axis.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Each triplet of numbers, in `position` attribute's array, defines a vertex with respective x, y, z coordinates.

Comment: No, the `position` attribute holds _triplets_ like this: `[ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ... ]`. So to make a `Vector3` of the first vertex, you _can_ do: `let v = new THREE.Vector3(mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[ 0 ], mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[ 1 ], mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[ 2 ]);`

Comment: You can also use [`let v = new Vector3().fromBufferAttribute( mesh.geometry.attributes.position, i )`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.fromBufferAttribute).

Comment: @TheJim01 alright great, but how do I change the position? As `v.x/y/z = position` doesn't work because we are creating a new vector.

Comment: [`Mesh.position`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Object3d#api/en/core/Object3D.position) is already a `Vector3`. So you can use the [`Vector3.set`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=vector3#api/en/math/Vector3.set) method with the individually referenced indices, or use `fromBufferAttribute` directly on `position` like this: `mesh.position.fromBufferAttribute( mesh.geometry.attributes.position, i );`

Comment: @TheJim01 thanks! post this as an answer, I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position attribute holds triplets like this: `[ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ... ]`.

So to make a `Vector3` of the first vertex, you can do:

```js
let v = new THREE.Vector3(
  mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[ 0 ], 
  mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[ 1 ], 
  mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array[ 2 ]
);
```

You can also use [`Vector3.fromBufferAttribute`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.fromBufferAttribute) like this:

```js
let v = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute( mesh.geometry.attributes.position, i );
```

Optimally, you don't have to create a new `Vector3`.

[`Mesh.position`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Object3d#api/en/core/Object3D.position) is already a `Vector3`, so you can use the [`Vector3.set`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=vector3#api/en/math/Vector3.set) method with the individually referenced indices, or use `Vector3.fromBufferAttribute` directly on position like this:

```js
mesh.position.fromBufferAttribute( mesh.geometry.attributes.position, i );
```